# Encoding & decoding serialized XML in the class which the methods are in

Tags: java, xml-serialization

I can't think of a way of describing it, basically I'm wondering if it is possible to write a method makes the current object become the decoded serialized XML.

I know that the saveTillXML works, as it generates an XML file which matches the state of the current Till object [but really I don't know that it does work, as the decoding fails]. However, I get these exceptions when I call the loadTillXML() method:

- java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
- java.lang.IllegalStateException
- java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

I call the saveTillXML() method when the window is closed, & the loadTillXML method in the Till's constructor.

I have all the gets & sets & argumentless constructors in the Till, & in all the clases which the Till uses.

```
public void saveTillXML() throws IOException{
    XMLEncoder encoder=new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("till.xml")));
    encoder.writeObject(this);
    encoder.close();        
}

public static void loadTillXML() throws IOException{
    XMLDecoder decoder=new XMLDecoder(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("till.xml")));
    decoder.readObject();       
    decoder.close();
}
```

The only thing I can think of is the fact that `decoder.readObject()` doesn't go into anything, which is probably should if I want to make the current instance be the XML it's decoding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to solve my problem. The loadTillXML needed a return method - Till - which then prompted me to think that it needs to be called outside Till. So I used it instead of `private Till till=new Till();` which was in the window.

The working method:

```
public static Till loadTillXML() {
    try{
        XMLDecoder decoder=new XMLDecoder(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("till.xml")));
        return (Till) decoder.readObject();     
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fNFE){
        System.out.println("Cannot find file");
        Till till=new Till();
        return till;
    }
}
```